# R extract maximum number after specific substring

Tags: r, regex

I have the following string in R:

```
 str <- "number_123 some text number_4"
```

Now, I want to extract the numbers 123 and 4 into vector of numerics. However, I was not able to come up with a regular expression to identify the numbers 123 and 4. The only identifier in this problem is "number_". I would like to extract the subsequent number which can be anything from 1 to 3 figures.

I found some regular expressions for some similar issues here. However I was not able to change it in such a way such that it fits my problem.

Thanks for your help!

Edit: sorry being not more precise. The actual string looks like the following:

```
str <- '\"number_123\"somtext 123 some more text\"number_1\" text'
```

As before I would like to extract the numbers following the substring \"number. Unfortunately, all your solutions did not work. I got the following warning message:

```
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: What is the code you have? What did not work? What is the *problem* with your *code*?

Comment: This `regex` should do it. `library(stringr)` `str_extract_all(str, "\\d{1,3}\\b")`.

Comment: please see my edited post. i hope i am more precise now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugly, but works:

```
foo <- "number_123 some text number_4"
as.numeric(gsub("number_", "", grep("number_", unlist(strsplit(foo, " ")), value = TRUE)))
```

Readable solution using pipe:

```
library(magrittr)
'\"number_123\"somtext 123 some more text\"number_1\" text' %>%
    strsplit(" ") %>% # Split character string per space
    unlist() %>%
    grep("number_", ., value = TRUE) %>% # Extract "words" with number_
    gsub("number_", "", .) %>% # Remove "number_" part
    gsub('"', "", .) %>% # Remove "number_" part
    gsub("[a-z]", "", .) %>% # Remove "number_" part
    as.numeric() # Turn into numbers

[1] 123   1
```

Comment: please see my edited post. i hope i am more precise now. i got the warning message as shown above. I obtained only NA's instead of the actual numbers.

Comment: @Rnewbie I edited my answer